# How to run a batch script contained in a variable in a Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have the following batch script as variable in my powershell script.

```
$DataIntegrityCheck = @"
@ECHO OFF
SET SETTING_HOME=""
SET BACKUP_SET="ALL"
SET BACKUP_DEST="ALL"
SET CRC_MODE="DISABLE-CRC"
"@
```

How can I run this batch script?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: why don't you set those EnvVars from inside powershell?

Comment: because the script is longer and does other things.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to execute that in batch to set environment variables, just use the `Environment` drive in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```
$Env:SETTING_HOME = '""'
$Env:BACKUP_SET = '"ALL"'
$Env:BACKUP_DEST = '"ALL"'
$Env:CRC_MODE = '"DISABLE-CRC"'
```

---

#### [`about_Environment_Provider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_provider?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: To have the same vars as in a batch you'll need to include the double quotes inside the single ones. Especially the 1st one won't be set at all.

Comment: @LotPings Good point, I usually use `SET "VAR=VAL"` in my scripts and missed what they were doing.